# Ubuntu 20.04 "virtualenv -p python3 ." command not working

Tags: python, 20.04, pip, virtualenv

After upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 `virtualenv -p python3 .` not working. I shows error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from virtualenv.run.app_data import AppDataAction
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/run/app_data.py", line 8, in <module>
    from virtualenv.util.lock import ReentrantFileLock
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/util/lock.py", line 11, in <module>
    from virtualenv.util.path import Path
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/util/path/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._pathlib import Path
  File "/home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/util/path/_pathlib/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

It seems that It work fine if I use `/usr/bin/virtualenv p python3 .` instead of `virtualenv -p python3 .` I have everything upgraded **pip3 is 20.1** and **virtualenv==20.0.20** also `six==1.14.0`  
is there any way to use **virtualenv** instead of **/usr/bin/virtualenv**?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `six`:

```
pip install six
```

or if you already have it:

```
pip uninstall six
pip install six
```

Comment: triedd that but problem remains same. I noticed though I'm using python3 still file is accessing /home/mahmud/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv. I wonder if its the issue?